# Magento 2 REST API - Generate Coupon

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, rest-api, coupon, coupon-codes

I am trying to generate a coupon through the Magento 2 REST API. It works, except that I cannot change the usage_limit and expiration_date. They are always set to the values of the rule. Is there any way around this, except creating a new rule for every new coupon?

Request:

```
{
    "coupon": {
        "rule_id":14,
        "code":"aaabbb",
        "usage_limit":10,
        "expiration_date":"2017-03-19",
        "type":"1"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "coupon_id": 11,
  "rule_id": 14,
  "code": "aaabbb",
  "usage_limit": 2147483647,
  "usage_per_customer": 0,
  "times_used": null,
  "expiration_date": "2064-03-14",
  "is_primary": null,
  "type": 1
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete API call with your rule description ? You can also edit the rule with this API call before generate coupon : PUT `/V1/salesRules/:ruleId`

Comment: What do you mean with complete API call? I POST this to V1/coupons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you've used salesrule which is used for coupon creation. It means that ***expiration_date*** and ***usage_limit*** fields will be pulled from the rule and set to the coupon. You must change rule used for that coupon in order to apply different ***expiration_date*** / ***usage_limit***.

Here is how it looks in ***\Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponReposito*ry**, pay attention to ***$coupon->setExpirationDate(..*.)** and ***$coupon->setUsageLimit(...)***:

```
public function save(\Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\CouponInterface $coupon)
{
    //if coupon id is provided, use the existing coupon and blend in the new data supplied
    $couponId = $coupon->getCouponId();
    if ($couponId) {
        $existingCoupon = $this->getById($couponId);
        $mergedData = array_merge($existingCoupon->getData(), $coupon->getData());
        $coupon->setData($mergedData);
    }

    //blend in specific fields from the rule
    try {
        $rule = $this->ruleFactory->create()->load($coupon->getRuleId());
        if (!$rule->getRuleId()) {
            throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('rule_id', $coupon->getRuleId());
        }
        if ($rule->getCouponType() == $rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Specified rule does not allow coupons')
            );
        } elseif ($rule->getUseAutoGeneration() && $coupon->getType() == $coupon::TYPE_MANUAL) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Specified rule only allows auto generated coupons')
            );
        } elseif (!$rule->getUseAutoGeneration() && $coupon->getType() == $coupon::TYPE_GENERATED) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Specified rule does not allow auto generated coupons')
            );
        }
        $coupon->setExpirationDate($rule->getToDate());
        $coupon->setUsageLimit($rule->getUsesPerCoupon());
        $coupon->setUsagePerCustomer($rule->getUsesPerCustomer());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Error occurred when saving coupon: %1', $e->getMessage())
        );
    }

    $this->resourceModel->save($coupon);
    return $coupon;
}
```

Only thing you can do here is to modify:

```
$coupon->setExpirationDate($rule->getToDate());
$coupon->setUsageLimit($rule->getUsesPerCoupon());
$coupon->setUsagePerCustomer($rule->getUsesPerCustomer());
```

Into something like:

```
if (is_null($coupon->getExpirationDate())) {
    $coupon->setExpirationDate($rule->getToDate());
}

if (is_null($coupon->getUsageLimit())) {
    $coupon->setUsageLimit($rule->getUsesPerCoupon());
}

if (is_null($coupon->getUsagePerCustomer())) {
    $coupon->setUsagePerCustomer($rule->getUsesPerCustomer());
}
```

Comment: How to overwrite the save method?

I tried creating a new Module in **app/code/CompanyName/SalesRule** and adding **Model/CouponRepository.php** to it as well as **etc/di.xml** with `<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponRepository" type="CompanyName\SalesRule\Model\CouponRepository" />`.

However, when running **setup:di:compile** after **setup:upgrade** it gives me the following error:
[RuntimeException] Source class "\CompanyName\SalesRule\Model\CouponRepository\CouponInterface" for "CompanyName\Sal esRule\Model\CouponRepository\CouponRepository" generation does not exist.